# Is it possible to include news into Google News if there is a non-news content under the same section?

Tags: seo, sitemap, googlebot, google-news

We want to include our news into Google News, and now performing research how to properly do this. At the moment we have the same base URL for news and non-news articles (analysis, interviews, etc.), e.g. *`www.example.com/news/{article-permalink}`*.

I read official documentation about [Getting into Google News](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/40787) but it's still not clear if we need to post all non-news articles under different base URL , or we can create [Google News Sitemap](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/75717?hl=en&ref_topic=4359874) and give there info about news. In favor of having just a news sitemap also says [this article](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/1734897) (option 3).

From development point of view, I would prefer to give authors possibility to mark articles as "news" and export them to news sitemap. This seems better, than rewriting logic for routing, rebuilding menu and making sure that old links didn't break.

So, the question is, in order to be included into Google News, is it safe to keep news and non-news articles under the same base URL , and just create a news sitemap?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to post anything in a different section. As long as your .htaccess file isn't blocking webcrawlers, bing and google will add it to news. If it is a blog, you might want to tag it "news", like you mentioned.

Then exporting it to the news sitemap would be highly recommended, yes. But you don't need to reorganize logic or have a separate section for news.